# how to write Java Code to let JPA/hibernate know where to look for Configuration files?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I'm a newbie to JPA, hibernate and Java itself.
I have somehow made my code work to access values from a DB.

When I extract my final jar of jars, I have a META-INF directory which has persistence.xml in it.

The hibernate.properties and hibernate.cfg.xml are also inside my jar.
So at runtime I'm unable to do any changes to these files since everything is inside jar.

I want to move persistence.xml, hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.properties outside jar and place them somewhere in deployment environment. I can do this but I don't know how to write Java Code to let hibernate know where to look for these files.

E.g. for log4j I can use PropertyConfigurator.configure("/opt/somepath/log4j.properties")  and tell log4j where log4j.properties file is present.

Could anyone please help me and direct me to some links where I can learn to load configuration for JPA and hibernate at runtime ?

I want to point to different DBs at runtime and test them without changing my jar of jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa)/[hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) scans classpath where looking for configuration files. You can always add to classpath directory/directories.

```
    MY_DIR1 = path/to/my/dir1
    My_DIR2 = /path/to/my/dir2
java -cp ${CLASSPATH}:${MY_DIR1}:${MY_DIR2} ...
```

Put `META-INF directory` to ${MY_DIR1} ( or/and ${MY_DIR2})

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it like this java -cp ${CLASSPAH}:./path/to/my/dir -jar Myjar.jar    But some links on web says that cp cannot be used with -jar. Any solution for this. I have used mvn clean install and mvn assembly:single to build my project Myjar.jar which is a jar of jars. How will I launch my jar from command line if I use -cp option ?

Comment: You right `When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.` So unpack your jar file.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of ajozwik Answer I solved my problem as follows ->

1. Created a /path/to/mydir directory at some place in my deployement system.
2. Moved META-INF and hibernate.properties and hibernate.cfg.xml to mydir.

   Directory Structure->

   mydir

   ```
     META-INF

         persistence.xml

     hibernate.properties

     hibernate.cfg.xml
   ```
3. Added mydir to class path while launching the executable.
4. Instead of launching the executable using

   ```
   java -jar Myjar.jar
   ```

   I launched it using

   ```
   java -cp Myjar.jar:/path/to/mydir MyMainClass
   ```